# XSLT remove middle part from string

Tags: string, xslt

Newbie XSLT question :
I have a string consisting of 3 parts separated by dots : `"2120.555.11111"`
How do I remove the middle part so I end up with `"2120.11111"` ?
(The string parts length might not be constant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath 1.0, individual steps for posterity:

```
substring-before('2120.555.11111', '.')       # '2120'
concat('2120', '.')                           # '2120.'
substring-after('2120.555.11111', '2120.')    # '555.11111'
substring-after('555.11111', '.')             # '11111'
concat('2120.', '11111')                      # '2120.11111'
```

combined, assuming `<X>` contains `'2120.555.11111'`:

```
concat(
  concat(substring-before(X, '.'), '.'),
  substring-after(substring-after(X, concat(substring-before(X, '.'), '.')), '.')
)
```

XPath 2.0+ is more flexible with string processing, this is one way to do it:

```
string-join(tokenize(X, '\.')[position() = 1 or position() = 3], '.')
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0 or higher, you could do simply:

```
replace(input, '\..*\.', '.')
```